# Please Recommend: jQuery simple gallery, expanding div and portrait or landscape images

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, image-gallery

I would like to know if anyone out there has had experience with any simple lightweight jQuery galleries.

My requirements for this particular project are quite simple, and I have made a genuine attempt to roll my own code, however this is just a bit puzzling for a beginner.

I have a large div that loads with an initial image.
Followed by an arbitrary number of thumbnail images with a link to their respective larger images. These images are all a similar width but with varying heights.

I would like to click a thumbnail, and have the large image div fade out the image, set the height to the new image (animated of course), then fade in the new image.

I have played with setting opacity to 1% to give that illusion as setting opacity to 0 seems to collapse the div altogether.

It doesn't need to have a slideshow, or any of that functionality but what is happening is at times the main div collapses altogether.

This is my code

```
$('.clickedimage').click(function() {
var newhref = $(this).attr('href'); // sets the variable for the new link
     var curheight = $('.bigpic').height(); //gets the current height
     $('.bigpic').attr('style', "height:"+curheight+"px" );
     $('#largeimage').fadeOut('slow', function(){
       $('#largeimage').attr('src',newhref);
       $('#largeimage').fadeTo('fast', 0.01, function(){
          var aheight = $('#largeimage').height();
        $('.bigpic').animate({
               height: aheight+'px'
        }, 500, function(){
              $('#largeimage').fadeTo('slow',1);
        });
       });  
    });
    return false; // do not follow through with the links and disable them
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are probably a bazillllion out there

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

Comment: yeh ... not that lightweight ... will prob roll my own ... alot of these overfluff :)